# Prolog Backtracking findall for two variables

Tags: prolog

I want to write a function residents(Housenumber,N) which

(1) gives me the amount of residents per house given the housenumber

AND

(2) when Housenumber is a variable, one is able to backtrack all resident counts for each house number.

Given are the following facts in the form of resident(Forename, Surname, Housenumber).

```
resident('Tim','Cook',1).
resident('Elisabeth','Cook',1).
resident('Thomas','Cook',1).
resident('George','Cook',1).
resident('Steve','Jobs',2).
resident('Lisa','Jobs',2).
resident('Karen','Jobs',2).
resident('Mark','Zuckerberg',3).
resident('Priscilla','Zuckerberg',3).
```

The second condition should work like:

```
residents(X,N).
X = 1,
N = 4,
X = 2,
N = 3,
X = 3,
N = 2.
```

I tried the following attempt.

```
residents(X,N):-
findall(X,resident(_,_,X),L),
length(L,N).
```

The first condition is satiesfied, however, the second condition gives me the total amount of all residents, not clustered for each house. I also tried the bagof and setof predicates but it did not help. Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `findall/3` automatically quantifies over the free variables (first and last name here) such that all solutions for the same adress get merged. Have a look at `bagof/3`[(see e.g. the SWI Documentation)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3), it allows you to manually quantify (which is not necessary here). To find the number of people living at the address, the list `L` also needs to collect the names of the residents per number, not the number itself:

```
?- bagof(X-Y, resident(X,Y,Z), Zs), length(Zs, N).
Z = 1,
Zs = ['Tim'-'Cook', 'Elisabeth'-'Cook', 'Thomas'-'Cook', 'George'-'Cook'],
N = 4 ;
Z = 2,
Zs = ['Steve'-'Jobs', 'Lisa'-'Jobs', 'Karen'-'Jobs'],
N = 3 ;
Z = 3,
Zs = ['Mark'-'Zuckerberg', 'Priscilla'-'Zuckerberg'],
N = 2.
```

Comment: Can't upvote due to too less reputation but thank you!

Answer (score -4):

Often complicated machinations with  `bagof`  and  `setof`  are indications that the data model needs work .
When a prolog predicate represents a data term it is good to think of it like a database table .
The name of the predicate is correspondent to the name of the database table .
The argument of the predicate are correspondent to the field within the database table .
For example : if designing and normalizing a database table then certainly a "resident" would not store a  *value*  of a house number ; instead the "resident" has a  *reference*  to a "house" and a "house" is an  *entity*  unto itself .

```
  :- [library('lists')] .
  :- source .

  :- initialization demo .

  (
     demo
  )
  :-
  (
          ?- residents(HOUSEi,COUNTi) 
  )
  .

  (
          residents(_houseI_,_countI_)
  )
  :-
  (
          house(_houseI_)
          ,
          house_residents(house(_houseI_),_residentS_)
          ,
          length(_residentS_,_countI_)
  )
  .

  (
          house_residents(_houseO_,_residentS_)
  )
  :-
  (
          _houseO_
          ,
          _queryO_ = resident(_,_houseO_)
          ,
          setof(_queryO_,_queryO_,_residentS_)
  )
  .

  house(1) .
  house(2) .
  house(3) .

  resident(name(first('Tim'),last('Cook')),house(1)).
  resident(name(first('Elisabeth'),last('Cook')),house(1)).
  resident(name(first('Thomas'),last('Cook')),house(1)).
  resident(name(first('George'),last('Cook')),house(1)).
  resident(name(first('Steve'),last('Jobs')),house(2)).
  resident(name(first('Lisa'),last('Jobs')),house(2)).
  resident(name(first('Karen'),last('Jobs')),house(2)).
  resident(name(first('Mark'),last('Zuckerberg')),house(3)).
  resident(name(first('Priscilla'),last('Zuckerberg')),house(3)).
```

Comment: I tried to run your code on GNU Prolog, SWI and Yap but it only works with the latter. Perhaps you could change your code that it works for more implementations? It should not be too hard because e.g. `library(lists)` is not used. If you reformat dropping the unneccessary parenthesis, the code becomes also much more readable.

Comment: with swipl an irrelevant error message because of the (apparently) unusual `:- source` but the code still works with correct answers from the top-level .